# Linux Shell .sh, Search Database

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron, sh

I'm quite new to Shell Bash scripts and am hitting a wall for a command to first search the database and then report on any entries which are not correct.

The database should be holding entry A,B,C only however the only way I can find to use, if to get the Shell to report those that are using X, Y.

The problem is X, Y keep changing.

Here's an example of what I have currently.

---

```
MAILADDR="me@yahoo.com"

# Look for a database table entry with X and add to a txt file

find /var/lib/mysql -type f -name '*configuration.MYD' -print0 | xargs -0 grep -il 'X' > /root/output_search_results1.txt

# Look for a database table entry with Y and add to a txt file

find /var/lib/mysql -type f -name '*configuration.MYD' -print0 | xargs -0 grep -il 'Y' > /root/output_search_results2.txt

# IF X file was populated then email it.

if [ -s /root/example_search_results1.txt ]
then
        mutt -s "Which database list example X" $MAILADDR < /root/example_search_results1.txt
        rm -f /root/example_search_results1.txt

fi

# IF Y file was populated then email it.

if [ -s /root/example_search_results2.txt ]
then
        mutt -s "Which database list example Y" $MAILADDR < /root/example_search_results2.txt
        rm -f /root/example_search_results2.txt

fi
```

---

PROBLEM: X and Y are often changing, so I ideally want the script to ONLY report if an entry is not equal to A, B or C (which are fixed) and then output that to a txt which is emailed to me.

I do hope someone can help

Have a great day.

Comment: where does your code reference anything about 'A,B,C', that is just confusing a confusing question. Sorry, but good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the "-v" option to grep.

From the grep man page :

```
-v, --invert-match
Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.
```

So you would have to change your grep command to :

```
grep -il -v 'A' -v 'B' -v 'C'
```

Comment: Thanks. You are suggesting to try 

find /var/lib/mysql -type f -name '*configuration.MYD' -print0 | xargs -0 grep -il -v '*hello*' > /root/results.txt

Comment: Where does this "*hello" come from ? If you just want to "invert" the command you used in the question, so it looks for "NOT A and NOT B and NOT C" instead of "X or Y", you could do it with _find /var/lib/mysql -type f -name 'configuration.MYD' -print0 | xargs -0 grep -il -v 'A' -v 'B' -v 'C' > /root/results.txt_

Comment: Well here a true example which will help explain better:
##
#!/bin/bash
#
MAILADDR="me@yahoo.com"

find /var/lib/mysql -type f -name '*configuration.MYD' -print0 | xargs -0 grep -il -v 'www.paypal.com*' > /root/results.txt


if [ -s /root/results.txt ]
then
        mutt -s "Results where www.paypal.com was not present" $MAILADDR < /root/results.txt
        rm -f /root/paypal_hack_results.txt
fi

### NOTE. The www.paypal.com could be one of three
### 'www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'
### 'www.paypal.com/us/webscr'
### 'www.paypal.com/uk/websr'

I hope that helps?

Comment: I suggest you test this code to see if it fits your needs. I can't find anything to add to my previous answers.

Comment: Hi Louis, I have fresh eyes today ;)

It seems that the grep is working but the reason it is reporting so many results is because the configuration.MYD contains multiple table fields, Therefore I really want the grep to ONLY look in one configuration.MYD field called "configuration_value" held in a row which has "configuration_key" equal = "MODULE_PAYMENT_PAYPAL_HANDLER".  Back to the drawing board as this has become a lot more complicated ;)

Comment: My guess is that you'd better do this with SQL queries rather than trying to analyse a mysql datafile with grep.